# How to convert scientific notation value to float

Tags: python, type-conversion, scientific-notation

I have txt files in the format:

```
 6.3894e+02 1.7316e+02 6.6733e+02 1.9942e+02 9.8697e-01
 6.4355e+02 1.7514e+02 6.8835e+02 2.0528e+02 9.7908e-01
```

I want to convert all these values into float as in:

```
 638.94 173.16 667.33 199.42 98.697
 643.55 175.14 688.35 205.28 97.908
```

My code is:

```
   import os
   for i in os.listdir():
       if i.endswith(".txt"):
          with open(i, "r+") as f:
               content = f.readlines()
               for line in content:
                   f.write(float(line))
```

Comment: `float(line)` would only make sense if the line consisted of a single float rather than several floats as in your example. You need to iterate over `line.split()`

Comment: You can't update the file the way you're doing it. You're writing the replacement line *after* the line you just read, which overwrites the next line.

Comment: Are you converting from string to string?  How do you decide how many decimal places to keep?

Comment: yes, that was a silly mistake, i need to iterate over line.split(), thank you everyone for the suggestions, helped a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't update a file in place like that. You can use the [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput) module for that.

You need to split the line at whitespace, parse each of the numbers as floats, then write them the way you want.

You can also use `glob()` to match all the `.txt` files instead of using `os.listdir()` and `.endswith()`. And since `fileinput` allows you to give it a list of files, you don't need the `for` loop.

```
import fileinput
from glob import glob


with fileinput.input(files=glob("*.txt"), inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        nums = map(float, line.split())
        print(*nums)
```

Comment: how can I decide how many decimal places to go. Like for example : 8.0166e-05 is still not converted into float value.

Comment: You realize that IS a float value, don't you? It's just another way of printing it.

Comment: It's used by default if there would be lots of leading zeroes after the decimal point. So it prefers `8.0166e-05` instead of `.000080166`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for all the rows:

```
   text = "6.3894e+02 1.7316e+02 6.6733e+02 1.9942e+02 9.8697e-01"
    numbers = text.split()
    numbers_float = [float(x) for x in numbers]
```